# ¿Como eliminar la distancia de un contenido al otro?

Tags: html, css, responsive

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, quiero reducir la distancia entre los iconos y la dirección de gmail, están demasiado separados y no se que es lo que esta causando conflicto en mi `mediaquery` o que línea debo agregar.

```css
  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .footer-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .contact-us {
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .fuente-direccion {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  }
  .social-media {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
  .social-media-icon {
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  }
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="contenedor footer-content">
    <div class="contact-us">
      <h2 class="brand">Direccion Oficina </h2>
      <h5 class="fuente-direccion"><br>Diagonal 13 Transversal sexta.<br>Avenida Circunvalar <br>Florencia, Caquetá</h5>
      <h2 class="brand">Mas Informacion </h2>
      <h5 class="fuente-direccion"><br>3212546362<br>3212547562<br>funeralesebenezerp@gmail.com</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="social-media">
      <a href="https://web.facebook.com/funeralesebenzer" class="social-media-icon">
        <i class='bx bxl-facebook'></i>
      </a>
      <a href="https://wa.me/3212547562" class="social-media-icon">
        <i class='bx bxl-whatsapp'></i>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/funeralesebenezer01/?hl=es" class="social-media-icon">
        <i class='bx bxl-instagram'></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <p class="parrafo-nota">Funerales ebenezer aclara que para solicitudes de servicios exequiales llamar directamente por interno o a las lineas</p>
</footer>
```

Como pueden ver hay clases que no agregue en los `mediaquerys` simplemente porque ya se están adaptando bien desde el código original.

Comment: Buen día, podrías darnos el código completo CSS de todo ese contenedor footer para que sea reproducible tu problema?... Si es muy largo, puedes crear un proyecto en https://codepen.io/ y compartirnos el enlace.

Comment: ok. gracias por tu amabilidad

Comment: pero no cpmprendo. te refieres al footer del mediaquery o el general.? porque si es el mediaquery ya lo puse completo. muchas gracias

Comment: Sí, el general. podrías adjuntarlo en https://codepen.io/ y compartir por aquí el enlace?

Comment: En que caja esta el espacio sobrante, en contact-us o en social-media? Esto lo podes averiguar usando las herramientas de desarrollador, superponiendo el puntero en cada div te va a mostrar las cajas para ver donde esta el problema.

Comment: No estás cerrando el último `div` , justo antes del cierre del `footer`. Posiblemente no es la solución, pero debes tener cuidado con esos detalles.